# Store past states of NSMutableArray in another NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

I need to create an array that keeps track of the history of an existing array. I am doing this by storing the tracked array into another:

```
[array2 addObject: array1];
```

As `array1`, changes I want `array2` to contain the different revisions of it. The problem I am getting is that when `array1` changes, all instances of `array2` change with it, but I would like it to retain the original value of `array1`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Nevermind guys, I solved the problem by using: [array2 addObject: [array1 mutableCopy]];

Comment: Make sure that if you aren't using ARC that you do `[array2 addObject: [[array1 mutableCopy] autorelease]];`

Comment: Feel free to [post your own answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120215/ended-up-solving-my-own-problem-question-what-to-do-with-the-post) if you like (there may be a delay before you can do this). Deletion is also an option if you prefer that.